# Change facet grid labels and order of facets using labeller

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way of changing **both** the labels and the order of facets using the labeller function in ggplot2? I can do each separately but not both.

```
library(ggplot2)
facet.labs <- c("very old", "old", "new")
names(facet.labs) <- sort(unique(mtcars$gear))

# This successfully changes the labels
mtcars |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(~gear, labeller = labeller(gear = facet.labs))

# This successfully changes the order of facets
mtcars |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(~factor(gear, levels = c(5, 4, 3)))

# You would expect this to change both but it looks exactly like the one above, i.e. changed order but not labels
mtcars |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(~factor(gear, levels = c(5, 4, 3)), labeller = labeller(gear = facet.labs))
```

What I want is the order and names of labels "new", "old", "very old".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit 1

I don't think there's a way to use `labeller` like that, sorry. Perhaps you can you change your 'gear' variable into a labelled factor in your `facet_wrap()` instead? E.g.

```r
library(ggplot2)

facet.labs <- c("very old", "old", "new")
names(facet.labs) <- sort(unique(mtcars$gear))
facet.labs
#>          3          4          5 
#> "very old"      "old"      "new"

mtcars |>
  ggplot(aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(~factor(gear,
                     levels = names(facet.labs)[order(facet.labs, c(5,4,3))],
                     labels = facet.labs[order(facet.labs, c(5,4,3))]))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### Original answer

You can convert gear to a factor before passing it to ggplot, e.g.

```r
library(ggplot2)
facet.labs <- c("very old", "old", "new")
names(facet.labs) <- sort(unique(mtcars$gear))
facet.labs
#>          3          4          5 
#> "very old"      "old"      "new"

mtcars |> 
  dplyr::mutate(gear = factor(gear, levels = c(5, 4, 3))) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(~gear, labeller = labeller(gear = facet.labs))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Would that work for your use-case?

Comment: Unfortunately no. In the real world example this is all part of a function so it really needs to be handled separately by the facet_grid call.

Comment: Ahh, yep, that makes sense - I've edited my answer with another potential workaround, but looking at the source code for `labeller` (https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/main/R/labeller.R) I can't see how to use it in the straightforward way you expect it to work, sorry

Comment: Your Edit 1 answer does the trick and is exactly what I needed! Thanks